# Is the Flash video fallback for HTML5 video built into the Flash plugin?

Tags: html, flash, html5-video

I understand how to use the HTML5 video tag except for one part: the flash fallback. In order to use a flash fallback do I just simply include the .flv file last in the list of source tags or is there some sort of special flash player I need to include like Flowplayer or that other one that reminds of a kangaroo (forgot the name).

My plan was to include the following code. Please let me know if the flash won't work this way:

```
<video controls width="400" poster="img/video/placeholder.png">
    <source src="img/video/ssi_intro.webm" type="Not Sure" />
    <source src="img/video/ssi_intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="img/video/ssi_intro.flv" type="Note Sure Again" />
</video>
```

I saw a ton of HTML5 video questions but not pertaining to this. This one makes me feel kind of dumb but thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You need to fallback to a video player written in flash, and not try to use HTML 5 video to a file encoded using Flash's old (Flash handles mp4 these days) video container. (Since the browser still won't support HTML 5 video)

Comment: Okay I understand most of that. So basically include the first two sources and remove the third .flv source and replace it with a `<object>` containing the flash player (all of this still enclosed in the `<video>` tag). The part I didn't understand is about using Flash's old encoding. If I understand right, if I just replace that last Flash source tag with an object containing the flash player it will work in browsers not supporting HTML5 right? I will take your advice and use a Flash player with a .mp4 file instead of an .flv but can you clarify your last sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an implementation, heck out [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). For background info, check out Mark Pilgrim's [Dive into HTML5 video chapter](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll definitely check it out. I actually first got myself up to speed with HTML5 with the book "HTML5 for Web Designers". It's a great introduction to the concepts and best practices.